# Response cards not displaying in website-lex

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I have created Lex Chatbot and developed a website and integrated this Chatbot. Its working fine.But response cards in the form of buttons are not showing up.I got to know that I have to invoke it from lambda function.So I included the response card code .It works ,but after displaying the buttons it goes back and asks the first slot value again.I dont know where I am wrong

Here is the expected conversation.

User:Hi
Lex:Please provide me your eid
User:e123456
Lex:Choose one of the impact below:
1.low 2.high 3.medium   (in form of buttons)
User clicks on low
Lex:Thanks,your ticket has been raised(expected)

What happens:

User:Hi
Lex:Please provide me your eid
User:e123456
Lex:Choose one of the impact below:
1.low 2.high 3.medium
User clicks on low
Lex:Please provide me your eid(goes back and asks the first slot value)

Here is my code:

```
import json
import logging
import re
import http.client
import mimetypes

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

  
def elicit_slot_response(output_session_attributes,intent_name,slot_to_elicit,message):
    responses= {
     'dialogAction': {
     'type': 'ElicitSlot',
     'slottoElicit':'slot_to_elicit',
     'message': {
      'contentType': 'PlainText',
      'content': message
                },
      'responseCard': {
                'version': '0',
                'contentType': 'application/vnd.amazonaws.card.generic',
                'genericAttachments': [
                    {
                    'title': 'title1',
                    'subTitle': 'subtitle',
                    "buttons":[ 
                     {
                        "text":"button 1",
                        "value":"value 1"
                     },
                     {
                        "text":"button 2",
                        "value":"value 2"
                     },
                     {
                        "text":"button 3",
                        "value":"value 3"
                     }
                        ]
                    }
                    ]
                                 }
     }
   }

    return responses    


def close():
    val=  {
             "dialogAction":
            {
                "fulfillmentState":"Fulfilled",
                "type":"Close",
                "message":
                 {
                     "contentType":"PlainText",
                     "content":"Hey your ticket has been raised"
                 }
                    }
                    
                }
    print(val)
    return val
    

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    val = ""
    slots = event['currentIntent']['slots']
    empidemployee= event['currentIntent']["slots"]["empidemployee"]
    latestdesc= event['currentIntent']["slots"]["latestdesc"]
    latestimpact= event['currentIntent']["slots"]["latestimpact"]
    output_session_attributes = event['sessionAttributes'] if event['sessionAttributes'] is not None else {}
    elicit_slot_response(output_session_attributes,'latestdetails','latestimpact',"impact")
    val=close()
    return val
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversation flow restarts because in the `ElicitSlot` response from the Lambda function containing the response cards, you are not returning the `slots` parameter which would contain the slot values already taken as an input from the user.

So, include the `slots` parameter in the [response](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html#using-lambda-response-format) the value for which could be `event['currentIntent']['slots']`.

Comment: Do you have idea about this particular post regarding resposnse cards.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62975180/response-cards-not-showing-amazon-lex